# Error MSB6006 "CL.exe" exited with code 2 in compile in visual studio c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I work on a c++ console project. this project has in msmpisdk platform. When I compiled in Visual Studio 2019 the error below occurred:

> "Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State...Error   MSB6006 "CL.exe" exited with code 2....C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VisualStudio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160-\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets 429."

I checked my code, it seems OK, also check ref lib of project, it seems OK.

I searched the web.

1. All functions return a value.
2. All variables set a value before using it.
3. I restarted Visual Studio and my computer.
4. I created new project and added the code, but the same error occurred.

but the same error occurred and my code doesn't compile.

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13948990/error-msb6006-cl-exe-exited-with-code-2

Comment: Not a duplicate, this is a new VS2019 bug.  The fix is released in version 16.3, currently in preview.  https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/405001/error-msb6006-clexe-exited-with-code-2.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at last  I found the problem.

- one of my variable ,initialized in algorithm .
- but compiler can not detect variable initialized before and raise error.
- see below code to see how this error raised.

```
#include "iostream"
class myclass1
{
    public: int _AMethod() { return 55; }
};

int main()
{
  myclass1* myVariable;
  int x = 0;
  if (x == 0)
  {
    myVariable = (myclass1*)malloc(sizeof(myclass1) * 5);
    //myVariable = init();
  }

  if (x == 0)
  {
    myVariable->_AMethod();
  }
}
```

now when compile this error occurred:
Error   MSB6006 "CL.exe" exited with code 2.

- all things in algorithm ok..
- but compiler raise error ..

this error can solved easily .. with init in definition, like below :

```
#include "iostream"
class myclass1
{
    public: int _AMethod() { return 55; }
};

int main()
{
  myclass1* myVariable=(myclass1*)malloc(sizeof(myclass1) * 5);
  int x = 0;
  if (x == 0)
  {
    //myVariable = (myclass1*)malloc(sizeof(myclass1) * 5);
    //myVariable = init();
  }

  if (x == 0)
  {
    myVariable->_AMethod();
  }
}
```