# Visual Studio keeps asking to "save file as"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

Why does my project in Visual Studio keep asking me to "save file as" though the file already exists?

Comment: I've got a similar problem as you describe above. It appeared after our company changed the TFS from TFS 2012 to TFS 2015. Randomly I get the question "Save File as" from Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: I've just upgraded to Visual Studio Update 2 and this seems to be a problem on my machine now too...this and a few unexpected modifications to my git integration.

Answer (score 1):

The file you are attempting to overwrite is either write protected (O/S level) or opened with a write lock by another application than Visual Studio.

Several version control applications will mark the file read only at the O/S level to prevent accidental changes to the file. TFS and VSS come to mind.

Comment: All of the changes were either unmodified files or locks.  The changes have been undone by the server. What steps should I do?

Comment: Any chance its got some source code protector on it, and so because you havent checked out the code its marking it as read only?

Answer (score 0):

Following on from @AdamZuckerman's answer:

To fix this issue, I've granted my user full control of the affected files which had (somehow!) been set to read/execute for my user.

Answer (score 0):

Could be caused by differences in VS versions/updates and the project/sln files. If you are working in a team then perhaps not all team members have the same VS and update.

For example if the project/sln file is stored using version 14.0.25420.1 (team member #1)

In the project file you will see something like this:
VisualStudioVersion = 14.0.25420.1

But your VS has a different version 14.0.25123.0 (team member #2), VS will attempt to change the version of the project/sln file which is why it asks to save it.